# Append to a CSV file which does not end with newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Suppose I have sample data in an Excel document:

| header1 | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| some data | testing | 123 |
| moar data | hello! | 456 |

I export this data to `csv` format with Excel, with *File > Save as > .csv*

This is my data `sample.csv`:

```
$ cat sample.csv
header1,header2,header3
some data,testing,123
moar data,hello!,456%
```

Note that Excel apparently does not add a newline at the end, by default -- this is indicated by `%` at the end.

Now let's say I want to append a row(s) to the CSV file. I can use `csv` module to do that:

```py
import csv


def append_to_csv_file(file: str, row: dict, encoding=None) -> None:
    # open file for reading and writing
    with open(file, 'a+', newline='', encoding=encoding) as out_file:
        # retrieve field names (CSV file headers)
        reader = csv.reader(out_file)
        out_file.seek(0)
        field_names = next(reader, None)
        # add new row to the CSV file
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, field_names)
        writer.writerow(row)


row = {'header1': 'new data', 'header2': 'blah', 'header3': 789}
append_to_csv_file('sample.csv', row)
```

So now a newline is added to end of file, but problem is that the data is added to end of last line, rather than on a separate line:

```
$ cat sample.csv 
header1,header2,header3
some data,testing,123
moar data,hello!,456new data,blah,789
```

This causes issue when I want to read back the updated data from the file:

```py
with open('sample.csv', newline='') as f:
    print(list(csv.DictReader(f)))

# [{..., 'header3': '456new data', None: ['blah', '789']}]
```

**Question**: so what is the best option to handle case when CSV file might not have *newline* at the end, when appending a row(s) to file.

#### Current attempt

This is my solution to work around case when appending to CSV file, but file *may not* end with a **newline** character:

```py
import csv


def append_to_csv_file(file: str, row: dict, encoding=None) -> None:
    with open(file, 'a+',  newline='', encoding=encoding,) as out_file:
        # get current file position
        pos = out_file.tell()
        print('pos:', pos)
        # seek to one character back
        out_file.seek(pos - 1)
        # read in last character
        c = out_file.read(1)
        print(out_file.tell(), repr(c))
        if c != '\n':
            delta = out_file.write('\n')
            pos += delta
        print('new_pos:', pos)
        # retrieve field names (CSV file headers)
        reader = csv.reader(out_file)
        out_file.seek(0)
        field_names = next(reader, None)
        # add new row to the CSV file
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, field_names)
        # out_file.seek(pos + 1)
        writer.writerow(row)


row = {'header1': 'new data', 'header2': 'blah', 'header3': 789}
append_to_csv_file('sample.csv', row)
```

This is output from running the script:

```
pos: 68
68 '6'
new_pos: 69
```

The contents of CSV file now look as expected:

```
$ cat sample.csv 
header1,header2,header3
some data,testing,123
moar data,hello!,456
new data,blah,789
```

I am wondering if anyone knows of an easier way to do this. I feel like I might be overthinking this a bit. I basically want to account for cases where CSV file might need a newline added to end, before a new row is appended to end of file.

If it helps, I am running this on a Mac OS environment.

Comment: I would suggest that you look at StringIO() capabilities: to write first to a string (any "writing to file" method will accept this object as a valid file and will write to it), add '\n' in front of it, and then append this string to a text csv file.

Comment: Another option: first add '\n' to the text csv file and then write your string to this file. Just add in the beginning `out_file.write('\n')`

Comment: @Alex would it still work if the file already had a newline at the end?

Comment: yes, but you would get a blank row/break line in the file in the place where you add your data. But if you want to guarantee that the code equally works with csv files that contain or not '\n' at the end, and the resources aren't a problem, nothing prevents you from first reading the text file to a string and checking if it ends with '\n'